# Flutter twilio_voice "Error Ringing - From: null, To: null, Direction: CallDirection.outgoing"

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, twilio

I have a problem on twilio_voice i do have already have an access token provided on twilio own server and after using the package i always get

```
await TwilioVoice.instance.call .place(from: myuserId , to: "+$number", extraOptions: extraData).then((value) => Get.toNamed(callPage!));

// Error log
Ringing - From: null, To: null, Direction: CallDirection.outgoing
Connection Failuer
Call Decline
```

I don't know where to start to find the fault on my backend or the package am using.

I don't have idea on which part.
can some help me to understand this.

Comment: Can you share the code and the context around it that causes this error?

Comment: Did you reach out why it cause this ?, as i face the same issue

Comment: Yes, I already also solve i forgot to close this the problem i was having was the token since the token am using was for browser extension came from the backend so i request to my backend for ios token. But if you have more problem contact me on my email a.chil6663@gmail.com